# Why does the code give me wrong triangle?

Tags: c

Make a triangle

```
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
********
*********
**********
***********
************
```

```
int rows = 12, i = 1, j = 1;

    while(i <= rows)
    {
        while(j <= i)
        {
            printf("*");
            j++;

        }
        printf("\n");
        i++;
        j=1;
```

I try to make a triangle like

```
********
*******
******
*****
****
***
**
*
```

but i am getting wrong.

Comment: Your program is doing exactly what you told it to do. Note, your posted code is incomplete.

Comment: If you want the triangle the other way up initialise `i = rows` and change the loop etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with

```
while(j <= i)
```

loop. Here is my solution:

```
int rows = 12, i = 1, j = 1;

while (i <= rows)
{
    while (j <= (rows - i +1))
    {
        printf("*");
        j++;

    }
    printf("\n");
    i++;
    j = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to reverse your loops. So for each loop in your code you're increasing the number of instances '*' is printed for each iteration of `i`. This is because `i` and `j` start at 1 and are increased until the number of iterations equals `rows`.

```
int rows = 12, i = 1, j = 1;

while (i <= rows)
{
    while (j <= (rows - i +1))
    {}
}
```

What you want is to start from 12, and decrement each time until you hit 0. So to start with you can loose the variable `rows`, and set `i` and `j` equal to 12. In the outer `while()` loop you want to decrement `i` and reset `j = i` each time the inner loop closes. The inner loop should print * and decrement j. Below is my solutions, but [Loc Tran's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3344587/loc-tran) answer works just as well.

```
int main(void){
int i = 12, j = 12;

while(i >=0)
{
    while(j >= 0)
    {
        printf("*");
        j--;

    }
    printf("\n");
    i--;
    j=i;
}
```

}

If this is for a school assignment (I had one quite similar in a 1st year course) I suggest you try understand why your code is different to the provided solutions.